# Running Selenium tests from Jenkins by invoking Ant

Tags: java, ant, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have an ant script that runs some Selenium tests. This works perfectly when run from Windows and also in a Putty bash terminal as `Jenkins` user, because the necessary `vncserver` is started up by the `jenkins` user previously and the `DISPLAY` variable is set to `:43`. I am invoking the same ant script in Jenkins CI server. The `DISPLAY` environment variable is configured in Jenkins web interface to `:43` too. The error message that I received is as below:

```
[junit] Setting selenium logging level to: FINE
[junit] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
[junit] Xlib: connection to ":43.0" refused by server
[junit] Xlib: No protocol specified
[junit]
[junit] Error: cannot open display: :43
[junit]
[junit] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:95)
[junit] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:157) 
[junit] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:93)
[junit] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:136) [junit] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:78)
[junit] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [junit] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [junit] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [junit] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [junit] at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
```

This message is very similar to the one I received when `vncserver` was started with a different user then the one who started the tests. However this is not the case now as I have double checked that both the testrunner and the VNC started is `jenkins`.

This is a Solaris server, if any details are required to help me please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not do anything differently but it got fixed a while ago, so it was a good approach. Magic just happens.. :-)

Comment: interesting...You didn't do anything, but answer is accept yourself... hahaha

Comment: yes. however maybe this little story gives someone a little hope, so i decided to answer the q and accept the a.